# XML will not display saved TimePicker data (CurrentHour)

Tags: java, android, xml

I have the following XML file giving me a mismatched tag error. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

(I'm attempting to view data from a TimePicker)

AddEditCountry java

```
import android.app.Activity; 
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener; 
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

public class AddEditCountry extends Activity {

 private long rowID; 
 private EditText nameEt;
 private EditText capEt;
 private EditText codeEt;
 private TimePicker timeEt;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
   {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
      setContentView(R.layout.add_country);

      nameEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameEdit);
      capEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.capEdit);
      codeEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.codeEdit);
      timeEt = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timeEdit);


      Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 

      if (extras != null)
      {
         rowID = extras.getLong("row_id");
         nameEt.setText(extras.getString("name"));  
         capEt.setText(extras.getString("cap"));  
         codeEt.setText(extras.getString("code"));  
         timeEt.setCurrentHour(extras.getInt("time"));  
      }

      Button saveButton =(Button) findViewById(R.id.saveBtn);
      saveButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

          public void onClick(View v) 
          {
             if (nameEt.getText().length() != 0)
             {
                AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object> saveContactTask = 
                   new AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object>() 
                   {
                      @Override
                      protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) 
                      {
                         saveContact();
                         return null;
                      }

                      @Override
                      protected void onPostExecute(Object result) 
                      {
                         finish();
                      }
                   }; 

                saveContactTask.execute((Object[]) null); 
             }

             else
             {
                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(AddEditCountry.this);
                alert.setTitle(R.string.errorTitle); 
                alert.setMessage(R.string.errorMessage);
                alert.setPositiveButton(R.string.errorButton, null); 
                alert.show();
             }
          } 
     });
   }

   private void saveContact() 
   {
      DatabaseConnector dbConnector = new DatabaseConnector(this);

      if (getIntent().getExtras() == null)
      {
          dbConnector.insertContact(nameEt.getText().toString(),
                  capEt.getText().toString(),
                  timeEt.getCurrentHour().toString(),
                  codeEt.getText().toString());
      }
      else
      {
         dbConnector.updateContact(rowID,
            nameEt.getText().toString(),
            capEt.getText().toString(),
            timeEt.getCurrentHour().toString(),
            codeEt.getText().toString());
      }
   }
}
```

add_country xml (where TimePicker data which is causing the crash is first entered into the system)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1">

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical" 
  android:padding="5dp">

  <EditText android:id="@+id/nameEdit"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:imeOptions="actionNext" 
     android:hint="@string/name_hint"
     android:inputType="textPersonName|textCapWords"/>

  <EditText android:id="@+id/capEdit"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:imeOptions="actionNext" 
     android:hint="@string/cap_hint"
     android:inputType="textPersonName|textCapWords"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Data Limit"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" />

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:text="10MB" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:text="Unlimited Data" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Bandwidth Limit"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" />

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:text="10kbs" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="Unlimited Bandwidth" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView02"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView02"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="WiFi Time Limit"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" />

<TimePicker
    android:id="@+id/timeEdit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1.0" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/codeEdit"
    android:inputType="textUri"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:lines="1"
    android:hint="@string/code_hint"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext" />




  <Button android:id="@+id/saveBtn" 
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
     android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
     android:text="@string/save_btn"/>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

view_country xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:stretchColumns="1" 
android:layout_margin="5dp">

<TableRow>         
<TextView 
style="@style/StyleLabel"
android:text="@string/name_lbl"/>
<TextView 
android:id="@+id/nameText" 
style="@style/StyleText"/>         
</TableRow>

<TableRow>         
<TextView 
style="@style/StyleLabel"
android:text="@string/cap_lbl"/>         
<TextView 
android:id="@+id/capText"
style="@style/StyleText"/>         
</TableRow>

<TableRow>       
<TextView 
style="@style/StyleLabel"
android:text="@string/code_lbl"/>                    
 <TextView 
android:id="@+id/codeText"
style="@style/StyleText"/>         
</TableRow>
<TableRow>         
<TextView 
style="@style/StyleLabel"
android:text="Linked Users"/>         
<TextView 

style="@style/StyleText"/>         
</TableRow>
<TableRow>         
<TextView 
style="@style/StyleLabel"
android:text="Time Limit"/>         
<TextView 
android:id="@+id/timeEdit"
style="@style/StyleText"/>  

</TableRow>
</TableLayout>  


ViewCountry java 


import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

public class ViewCountry extends Activity {

   private long rowID;
   private TextView nameTv;
   private TextView capTv;
   private TextView codeTv; 
   private TimePicker timeTv; 

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
   {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.view_country);

      setUpViews();
      Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
      rowID = extras.getLong(CountryList.ROW_ID); 
   }

   private void setUpViews() {
       nameTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nameText);
       capTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.capText);
       timeTv = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timeEdit);
       codeTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.codeText);
   }

   @Override
   protected void onResume()
   {
      super.onResume();
      new LoadContacts().execute(rowID);
   } 

   private class LoadContacts extends AsyncTask<Long, Object, Cursor> 
   {
      DatabaseConnector dbConnector = new DatabaseConnector(ViewCountry.this);

      @Override
      protected Cursor doInBackground(Long... params)
      {
         dbConnector.open();
         return dbConnector.getOneContact(params[0]);
      } 

      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(Cursor result)
      {
         super.onPostExecute(result);

         result.moveToFirst();
         // get the column index for each data item
         int nameIndex = result.getColumnIndex("name");
         int capIndex = result.getColumnIndex("cap");
         int codeIndex = result.getColumnIndex("code");
         int timeIndex = result.getColumnIndex("time");

         nameTv.setText(result.getString(nameIndex));
         capTv.setText(result.getString(capIndex));
         timeTv.setCurrentHour(result.getInt(timeIndex));
         codeTv.setText(result.getString(codeIndex));

         result.close();
         dbConnector.close();
      }
   } 


   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
   {
      super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
      MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
      inflater.inflate(R.menu.view_country_menu, menu);
      return true;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
   {
      switch (item.getItemId())
      {
         case R.id.editItem:
            Intent addEditContact =
               new Intent(this, AddEditCountry.class);

            addEditContact.putExtra(CountryList.ROW_ID, rowID);
            addEditContact.putExtra("name", nameTv.getText());
            addEditContact.putExtra("cap", capTv.getText());
            addEditContact.putExtra("code", codeTv.getText());
            addEditContact.putExtra("time", timeTv.getCurrentHour());
            startActivity(addEditContact); 
            return true;

         case R.id.deleteItem:
            deleteContact();
            return true;

         default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
      } 
   }

   private void deleteContact()
   {

      AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(ViewCountry.this);

      alert.setTitle(R.string.confirmTitle); 
      alert.setMessage(R.string.confirmMessage); 

      alert.setPositiveButton(R.string.delete_btn,
         new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
         {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int button)
            {
               final DatabaseConnector dbConnector = 
                  new DatabaseConnector(ViewCountry.this);

               AsyncTask<Long, Object, Object> deleteTask =
                  new AsyncTask<Long, Object, Object>()
                  {
                     @Override
                     protected Object doInBackground(Long... params)
                     {
                        dbConnector.deleteContact(params[0]); 
                        return null;
                     } 

                     @Override
                     protected void onPostExecute(Object result)
                     {
                        finish(); 
                     }
                  };

               deleteTask.execute(new Long[] { rowID });               
            }
         }
      );

      alert.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel_btn, null).show();
   }
}



Database Connector




import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;


public class DatabaseConnector {

private static final String DB_NAME = "WorldCountries";
private SQLiteDatabase database;
private DatabaseOpenHelper dbOpenHelper;

public DatabaseConnector(Context context) {
    dbOpenHelper = new DatabaseOpenHelper(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
}

   public void open() throws SQLException 
   {
      //open database in reading/writing mode
      database = dbOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
   } 

   public void close() 
   {
      if (database != null)
         database.close();
   }       

   public void insertContact(String name, String cap, String code, String time) 
           {
              ContentValues newCon = new ContentValues();
              newCon.put("name", name);
              newCon.put("cap", cap);
              newCon.put("time", time);
              newCon.put("code", code);

              open();
              database.insert("country", null, newCon);
              close();
           }


           public void updateContact(long id, String name, String cap,String code,  String time) 
           {
              ContentValues editCon = new ContentValues();
              editCon.put("name", name);
              editCon.put("cap", cap);
              editCon.put("time", time);
              editCon.put("code", code);

              open();
              database.update("country", editCon, "_id=" + id, null);
              close();
           }


           public Cursor getAllContacts() 
           {
              return database.query("country", new String[] {"_id", "name"}, 
                 null, null, null, null, "name");
           }

           public Cursor getOneContact(long id) 
           {
              return database.query("country", null, "_id=" + id, null, null, null, null);
           }

           public void deleteContact(long id) 
           {
              open(); 
              database.delete("country", "_id=" + id, null);
              close();
           }
}
```

LOGCAT:

```
03-22 04:40:09.319: D/Activity(2206): Activity.onPause(), editTextTapSensorList size: 0
03-22 04:40:09.479: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(2206): <ConfigWindowMatch:2165>: Format RGBA_8888.
03-22 04:40:09.479: D/memalloc(2206): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5d00d000 size:614400 offset:0 fd:69
03-22 04:40:09.569: D/memalloc(2206): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5d997000 size:614400 offset:0 fd:75
03-22 04:40:09.599: D/memalloc(2206): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5da3d000 size:614400 offset:0 fd:78
03-22 04:40:09.599: D/memalloc(2206): ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x5c989000 size:614400
03-22 04:40:09.599: D/memalloc(2206): ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x5ca41000 size:614400
03-22 04:40:09.599: D/memalloc(2206): ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x5cf66000 size:614400 
03-22 04:40:15.376: D/Activity(2206): Activity.onPause(), editTextTapSensorList size: 0
03-22 04:40:15.416: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(2206): <ConfigWindowMatch:2165>: Format RGBA_8888.
03-22 04:40:15.426: D/memalloc(2206): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5cf06000 size:614400 offset:0 fd:56
03-22 04:40:15.496: D/memalloc(2206): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5ddd3000 size:614400 offset:0 fd:60
03-22 04:40:15.516: D/memalloc(2206): ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x5d00d000 size:614400
03-22 04:40:15.516: D/memalloc(2206): ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x5d997000 size:614400
03-22 04:40:15.526: D/memalloc(2206): ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x5da3d000 size:614400
03-22 04:40:15.556: D/memalloc(2206): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5d00d000 size:614400 offset:0  fd:63
03-22 04:40:18.409: D/Activity(2206): Activity.onPause(), editTextTapSensorList size: 0
03-22 04:40:18.469: W/dalvikvm(2206): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception  (group=0x410889d8)
03-22 04:40:18.469: E/AndroidRuntime(2206): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-22 04:40:18.469: E/AndroidRuntime(2206): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity  ComponentInfo{com.nfc.linkingmanager/com.nfc.linkingmanager.ViewCountry}:  java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.TimePicker
03-22 04:40:18.469: E/AndroidRuntime(2206):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1960)
03-22 04:40:18.469: E/AndroidRuntime(2206):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1985)
03-22 04:40:18.469: E/AndroidRuntime(2206):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
03-22 04:40:18.469: E/AndroidRuntime(2206):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1151)
03-22 04:40:18.469: E/AndroidRuntime(2206):     at   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-22 04:40:18.469: E/AndroidRuntime(2206):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-22 04:40:18.469: E/AndroidRuntime(2206):     at  android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4477)
03-22 04:40:18.469: E/AndroidRuntime(2206):     at  java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-22 04:40:18.469: E/AndroidRuntime(2206):     at  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-22 04:40:18.469: E/AndroidRuntime(2206):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:788)
03-22 04:40:18.469: E/AndroidRuntime(2206):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
03-22 04:40:18.469: E/AndroidRuntime(2206):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-22 04:40:18.469: E/AndroidRuntime(2206): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.TimePicker
03-22 04:40:18.469: E/AndroidRuntime(2206):     at com.nfc.linkingmanager.ViewCountry.setUpViews(ViewCountry.java:38)
03-22 04:40:18.469: E/AndroidRuntime(2206):     at com.nfc.linkingmanager.ViewCountry.onCreate(ViewCountry.java:30)
03-22 04:40:18.469: E/AndroidRuntime(2206):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4701)
03-22 04:40:18.469: E/AndroidRuntime(2206):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1051)
03-22 04:40:18.469: E/AndroidRuntime(2206):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1924)
03-22 04:40:18.469: E/AndroidRuntime(2206):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Try opening the XML (file) in IE.

Answer (score 5):

This is the problem - the bottom line, which I've broken into multiple lines:

```
<TableRow>
  <TextView style="@style/StyleLabel" android:text="Time Limit"/>
  <TimePicker android:id="@+id/timeEdit" style="@style/StyleText"/> </TimePicker>
</TableLayout>
```

You haven't closed the `TableRow` element before closing the `TableLayout` element.

(Note that you would probably have seen this more easily yourself if you'd laid out your XML in a "naturally indented" style rather than having one long line at the bottom.)

I'd also expect whatever editor you're using to edit the XML to show the error pretty clearly, e.g. by underlining the `</TableLayout>`.

Comment: Changed it to <TextView style="@style/StyleLabel" android:text="Time Limit"/> <TimePicker android:id="@+id/timeEdit" style="@style/StyleText"/> </TimePicker> </TableRow> </TableLayout>

and I'm still getting a XML Mismatched Tag error after cleaning the project

Comment: @HelpWanted: And what does the editor show? Does the error have any more information? Have you tried just opening the file in a plain XML editor and seeing what that says?

Comment: Its showing a giant TimePicker. This is not what I need. I need the stored TimePicker data dispayed in here:

<TableRow>         
 <TextView 
    style="@style/StyleLabel"
    android:text="Time Limit"/>         
 <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/timeEdit"
    style="@style/StyleText"/>  

</TableRow>



(Ive included the JAVA which displays the stored TimePicker data above)

Comment: @HelpWanted: Sorry, I can't see how that comment relates to my comment at all. When I say "the editor" I mean an IDE view of the XML. Forget the Java - it's completely irrelevant to this. If the XML is invalid, the XML is invalid and nothing you do in the Java code will affect that. Concentrate on *just* making sure you've got valid XML first.

Comment: The Graphical Layout Editor displays a TimePicker if I use your source code. I need the timepicker data stored by the timepicker in the source code above (I've updated the description with a very detailed view of my source code so you can see where I'm saving the TimePicker data and where I'm trying to display it)

Comment: Should I be adding <TableRow>
  <TextView style="@style/StyleLabel" android:text="Time Limit"/>
  <TimePicker android:id="@+id/timeEdit" style="@style/StyleText"/> </TimePicker>
</TableLayout>

to add_country.xml or view_country.xml

(I'm thinking add_country (since this is where my TimePicker adds the currentHour to the database - and your code adds a new TimePicker) but your answer doesnt seem to fit since I don't have any TableLayouts in my add_country.xml - I just need to display the saved CurrentHour not display a new TimePicker

Comment: @HelpWanted: Your original question was *only* about invalid XML. That's what I helped with. If you've got a more Android-specific question, I suggest you ask that separately.